# How to add image numbers in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have a document in Google Docs which has a lot of images numbered sequentially. Every time I add a new image in the middle of the document I have to renumber all the image numbers along the document along with its references. How could I renumber the following images automatically, like we can do in LibreOffice using variables?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

so far it is not possible. You could take a look at Google Apps Scripts to create a macro that does that: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

I've just finished creating a Google Docs Add-on (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3641454?hl=en) that can number images and tables. It is going through the process of certification by Google and I hope to publish it soon :)

Regards

Comment: Did your add-on ever make it through? I'd be interested in this as well.

Comment: seems to be here: Captionizer by Filipe Werneck https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/captionizer/deemabgnpoamameafiackibdmgbloimo?utm_source=permalink

Comment: @Yoga link broken

Comment: And I can't find the way of numbering images - help

Comment: Updated link: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/captionizer/190342451111

Comment: The app is blocked by Google, apparently because it accessed sensitive information.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Crossref](https://github.com/davidrthorn/cross_reference/wiki/Overview). The way it works is that you higlight the text referring to a figure, which can be anything e.g. "Figure n" as the add on will replace it.

You then use Ctrl + K to make this into a link to a non existent bookmark such as "#figur_heights" where you can put any text you like after the "#figur_..." Do that for all the figures in the document and when you refer to a figure use an identical non existent bookmark, except it starts as "#fig_..." e.g. "#fig_heights". In this way it can number the figures consecutively and use matching  numbers for the in text references.

Finally you then need to go to Add ons > Crossref > Update and it will go through and update all the text for those bookmarks to the sequentially numbered Figure 1, Figure 2 etc. You need to do that whenever you change the order of the figures in your document, add a new reference etc, anything that will change the way the figures are numbered.

Comment: I have not been able to make it work, it just init and makes nothing

Comment: Did you create the text for the figures and link them to the nonexistent bookmarks?